# Easy way to convert a string to a number or null?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a slick way to convert a string to a number or null if it cannot be represented by a number?  I have been using the method below:

```
if _.isNaN( Number(mystring)  ) then null else Number(mystring)
```

Which works, but I'm curious if there is something that is shorter?  Possible, or is this the most succinct way?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care for "0", then you can use

```
+s||null
```

If you want to support `"0"`, then I don't have better than

```
1/s?+s:null
```

Comment: Awesome!  What does the `+` do? in this case?

Comment: It converts a string to a number if it's valid, or NaN otherwise.

Comment: Note: this approach won't work where `mystring` is "0".

Comment: @user2864740 You're damn right... Let me think one minute

Comment: what about `parseInt(myString)`?

Comment: @SumanBogati Issues is `0||null` null (in either `+x` or `parseInt(x,10)`). Darn the false-y values of JavaScript sometimes.

Comment: @dystroy:  i'll do you one char better: 1/s?+s:null

Comment: The second option yields null for the string "Infinity" or for a string representing a value larger than an IEEE double can represent.  Both of which may or may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is a small improvement to the OP's answer, and is fairly readable:

```
isNaN(mystring) ? null : +mystring
```