# JavaScript: convert string/number to a number or null, return 0 for 0?

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript I currently have this nice expression:

```
var b = {
   items: +a || null
};
```

This sets `b.items` to a Number if `a` is a String, or a Number greater than 0, and as `null` if `a` is `null`/`undefined`.

However, it also returns `null` if `a` is 0. Now I'd like to change it so that it returns 0 if `a` is 0. (This seems like the right way to handle real data: if it's zero, we want to know that it's zero, and if it doesn't exist, we want to know that too.)

I've looked [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636913/easy-way-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-or-null) and tried these two:

```
items: 1/a ? +a: null
items: isNaN(a) ? null : +a
```

but these both return 0 if `a` is null. They should return null.

Is there a way I can return 0 if `a` is 0, and `null` if it's undefined?

**Update: Here's a summary of everything the expression needs to do:**

```
"72" -> 72
"0" -> 0
1 -> 1
0 -> 0
null -> null
undefined -> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specifically test for null and undefined

```
var b = {
    items: ('undefined' === typeof a || null === a) ? null : +a
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of `a` in ternary operator.

```
var b = {
    items: typeof (+a) == 'number' ? +a : null
};
```

Demo:

```js
var b = {
  items: typeof (+"0") == 'number' ? +"0" : null
};


alert(b.items);
```

**EDIT**

Hack to check `null`.

```js
function f(a) {
  return isNaN('' + a) ? null : parseFloat(a)
}


alert(f(0));
alert(f(null));
alert(f(undefined));
```

Comment: I want to convert strings too, though... including the string `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var b = {
   items: +a ||(a==0?0:null)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
var b = {
   items: a != null? +a : null
};
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15992131/1494833

Comment: @Richard, it returns null, what should it return rather?

Comment: it does? I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` (testing in the console).

Comment: @Richard, that just points to that you didn't define `a` before testing. For me, just adding `var a = undefined;` before the snippet above makes it work fine.